# How to enable/disable a view element inside CollectionView Cell from UITapGestureRecognizer function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm pretty sure you didn't get the idea of the question from the heading, so let me explain.

I have a view called **TextView2** inside the **CollectionViewCell**. This view repeats in every cell. Inside this **TextView2** there is an **imageView** of a download button. I want to disable this **imageView** whenever the user clicks on the **TextView2**.

I created a **tapGestureRecognizer** for **textView2** and all seems to work fine except the **imageView** that disables when clicked is the **imageView** inside the last **collectionViewCell**. How do I make it to disable the **imageView** of the cell that I clicked? I know I have to make use of the index path somehow but I couldn't make it work.

This is a rough idea of how the code work.

```
var downloadImageView = UIImageView()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as? JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
    let textView2 = EdgeInsetLabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0) , width: CGFloat(250), height: CGFloat(70)))
    downloadImageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 110, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
    downloadImageView.image = downloadIcon
    downloadImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 190, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20)
    textView2.addSubview(downloadImageView)

    let tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action:  #selector(messageTapped(_:)))
textView2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    cell.addSubview(textView2)
    return cell

}

@objc func messageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    downloadImageView.isHidden = true

}
```

Please help me to make it to disable the **imageView** of the cell clicked instead of the last cell of **collectionView**. I am a beginner in Swift all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your downloadImageView is a property of the ViewController, so you have only one downloadImageView when you should probably make a new one for every cell. Because you only have one ImageView, the image view affected by the messageTapped will be the one in the cell which is dequeued last.
You should make a new imageView in the cellForItemAt function, and then in messageTapped you can write something like this, to obtain access to the cell tapped:

```
@objc func messageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   let point = sender.location(in: theNameOfYourCollectionView)
   if let index = collectionView.indexPathForRow(at: point){
      if let myCell = collectionView.cellForRowAt(at: index) as? JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell{
          for sub in myCell.subviews{
              if let textV = sub as? EdgeInsetLabel{
                  for sub in textV.subviews{
                      if let image = sub as? UIImageView{
                          image.isHidden = true
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll try this out and let you know